# Rename Pandas column headers using dictionary keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the headers of my dataframe based on a dictionary, but I need to reference the columns as lower case.

```
dict = {'january': 'Jan', 'february': 'Feb', etc.}
df.columns = ['JANUARY','FEBRUARY', etc.]
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
df = df.rename(columns=dict)
```

But this wouldn't work because the columns don't equal the keys. Is there a way to map the dict values to the headers without making a new dict or lower casing all the column headers? Can I map by `df.columns.str.lower()` somehow?

Comment: Not directly the question, but in your case you could do `df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[:3].capitalize())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.lower` + `map` on `df.columns` to modify it:

```
dct = {'january':'Jan','february':'Feb', 'march':'Mar', 'april':'Apr'}
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().map(dct)
```

For the following DataFrame:

```
    JANUARY  FEBRUARY  MARCH  APRIL
0         0         0      1      0
1         0         1      1      1
```

the above code produces:

```
    Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr
0     0    0    1    0
1     0    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you need to change your header to something like:

```
jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
```

I mean, not only the value of the dictionary but also all in lowercase.

So, the following approach will help you to get your answer:

```py
import pandas as pd


dic = {'january': 'Jan', 'february': 'Feb', 'march': 'Mar', 'april': 'Apr', 'may': 'May', 'june': 'Jun', 'july': 'Jul',
       'august': 'Aug', 'september': 'Sep', 'october': 'Oct', 'november': 'Nov', 'december': 'Dec'}

data = {'JANUARY': [2, 16, 19, 15],
        'FEBRUARY': [20, 8, 4, 5],
        'MARCH': [1, 2, 4, 11],
        'APRIL': [14, 4, 20, 13],
        'MAY': [6, 4, 13, 1],
        'JUNE': [6, 2, 19, 14],
        'JULY': [17, 8, 13, 19],
        'AUGUST': [0, 8, 9, 15],
        'SEPTEMBER': [6, 3, 3, 18],
        'OCTOBER': [1, 8, 6, 15],
        'NOVEMBER': [18, 20, 8, 3],
        'DECEMBER': [18, 17, 7, 16]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

Result:

```sh
   JANUARY  FEBRUARY  MARCH  APRIL  ...  SEPTEMBER  OCTOBER  NOVEMBER  DECEMBER
0        2        20      1     14  ...          6        1        18        18
1       16         8      2      4  ...          3        8        20        17
2       19         4      4     20  ...          3        6         8         7
3       15         5     11     13  ...         18       15         3        16
```

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().map(dict((k, v.lower()) for k, v in dic.items()))

print(df)
```

result:

```sh
   jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
0    2   20    1   14    6    6   17    0    6    1   18   18
1   16    8    2    4    4    2    8    8    3    8   20   17
2   19    4    4   20   13   19   13    9    3    6    8    7
3   15    5   11   13    1   14   19   15   18   15    3   16
```

Comment: Thanks Reza. I think this should work. The results are lower case, but I think a .str.title() at the end of the last statement should fix that